# Close iAd interstitial with a Game Controller

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad, mfi, gamecontroller

I'm making a Sprite Kit game that fully supports wireless game controllers.

Using one means you won't always be able to touch your screen for some little actions.
(For example, if you use an iPad as a TV game console with an HDMI cable and a game controller playing from a couch)

On a stage of adding ads to the game, I stumbled on this question:

**Is there any way at all to close iAd interstitial with a MFi Game Controller?**

Comment: yes, you should continue to receive input from the controller so you can do whatever with that input, like closing the ad programmatically

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I use [UIViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation] to show the ads. This way I can't even set up a delegate to receive calls. But I've never heard of controlling the actual iAd element. How's that?

Comment: I mean you can set up the view controller to receive mfi input before showing the ad, see if it continues to receive input when the ad is presented. If not set it up differently. Hard to say without seeing any code, just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, there is no way. I decided to not show any ads when using a wireless game controller.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do this with:

```
[UIViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

You would need to present the ad yourself using a solution based around `ADInterstitialAd` and it's `presentInView:` method.  I.e. create a custom `UIViewController`, you then have full control.

The `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` solution is for simple situations, if you need more you need to build it yourself.